# How to do parallel indexing on files (not on HDFS) in Solr?

Tags: indexing, solr, parallel-processing

I am not able to find a feasible solution so far, here is my env:

1. Cloudera Solr
2. 1TB data from file system to be indexed
3. data format is JSON only

I know how to do indexing on file system like single file or folder, but how do I do that in a parallel way? As the data is not and cannot be put on HDFS, it limits the possible solution of using MapReduce or Spark tool.

Does anyone encounter the same need? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Writing an indexer using a programming language you're familiar with that takes a slice of the available files is probably the best bet, then running multiple copies of this indexer (or using multiple threads if that's easily available) - allowing you to submit content in parallel and from multiple servers if necessary.

Don't use explicit commits in each client - use commitWithin so that you only commit every 60 seconds (or 10 minutes, or .. whatever interval that works for you).

Comment: what?! wouldn't this be a very common and popular need? I have been thinking there should be a built-in function to do so, for example, Cloudera provides MapReduce and Spark to do the parallel indexing on HDFS